# My app looks horrible in older/smaller phone

Tags: android

I've been using my galaxy s9+ for creating good looking app, but now I tried with old galaxy s5, its very old and my app looks horrible in it. Is it just simply too old, or will this happen to newer, better resolution phones too?

My main problem is the main menu, that has plenty of space in s9+ but can't see last button in s5, do I need to do something differently? I've been using Relative layouts, and sometimes androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes

Comment: Ultimately, to be confident in your results you'll need to set up emulators for screen size and density and API level.  This leads to a bunch of emulators so use a naming convention in AVD.  On occasion the PreLaunch report (screenshots) in the dev console will show issues as well with the varying emulators they use.

Comment: The most common solution that I have seen developers use is to optimize for a mid size phone and wrap everything in a scroll view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SDP - a scalable size unit**

> https://github.com/intuit/sdp

This is the library I have been using for my app. Its easy and it automatically manage the size of layout and view.It changes dimension according to the screen size. Change all you dimension in _sdp.

Comment: Why it says: "for text views please refer to ssp which is based on the sp size unit for texts." but there is no ssp in example file?

Answer (score 1):

I think it been answered before but I would like to share my idea or way to resolve text size problem over difference resolution devices. Many android developer sites suggest that we have to use sp unit for text size which will handle text size for difference resolution devices. But I am always unable to get the desired result. So I have found one solution which I am using from my last 4-5 projects and its working fine. As per my suggestion, you have to place the text size for each resolution devices, which is bit tedious work, but it will fulfill your requirement. Each developer has must listen about the ratio like 4:6:8:12 (h:xh:xxh:xxxh respectively). Now inside your project res folder you have to create 4 folder with dimens file e.g.

```
res/values-hdpi/dimens.xml
res/values-xhdpi/dimens.xml
res/values-xxhdpi/dimens.xml
res/values-xxxhdpi/dimens.xml
```

Now inside dimens.xml file you have to place text sizes. I am showing you code for values-hdpi, similarly you have to place code for other resolution values/dimens.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<dimen name="text_size">4px</dimen>
</resources>
```

For other resolutions it is like xhdpi : 6px, xxhdpi : 8px, xxxhdpi : 12px. This is calculated with the ratio (3:4:6:8:12) I have written above. Lets discuss other text size example with above ratio. If you want to take text size of 12px in hdpi, then in other resolution it would be

```
hdpi : 12px
xhdpi : 18px
xxhdpi : 24px
xxxhdpi : 36px
```

This is the simple solution to implement required text size for all resolutions. I am not considering values-mdpi resolution devices here. If any one want to include text size for this resolution then ration is like 3:4:6:8:12. In any query please let me know. Hope it will help you people out.

Comment: Does this also effect to boxes and such? At this point they don't scale at all eather right now, for example I have button which is from side to side and about centimeter high, its actually little bit higher in Galaxy s5, I assume thats because s9+ has a loot higher resolution?

Comment: Yes it will. Android device will pick automatically dimensions from the respective dimensions folder(hdpi ,xhdpi ,xxhdpi,xxxhdpi).
One option is using dimensions in dp (Density Pixel ). It work fine but not accurate as this above mentioned solution.

Comment: I've been using only dp and sp

Comment: Then you can use above mentioned approach, That is working fine I have been using for years

Comment: and hdpi is targeted phones like my s5, which are small and has now days relatively small resolution, and xxx most largest tablets, and all others everything between those devices?

Comment: LDPI: Portrait: 200 X 320px

MDPI: Portrait: 320 X 480px

HDPI: Portrait: 480 X 800px

XHDPI: Portrait: 720 X 1280px

XXHDPI: Portrait: 960 X 1600px

XXXHDPI: Portrait: 1440 x 2560px

This might help you out to understand

Comment: So from left top corner where is "Android" I change "Project" and there app->src->main->res, right click on res->new->android resource directory? Or do I go to values right click on it -> new-> values resource file?

Comment: create this folder manually in res directory with a name like values-hdpi, res/values-xhdpi and so on.. After that add dimension file to them and set dimensions accordingly

Comment: I wonder, is this making every text standard size? Cause if it is, then I can't use this method, cause I have lot of activities and they have different size of texts inside

Comment: And also when im making new resource directory, do I take from "Available qualifiers" -> size?

Answer (score 0):

yes.. as mentioned by Rajesh Kumar Sharma you can you this library https://github.com/intuit/sdp.    I have used in so many projects.. & it works well...
good luck.